# Creating a Wizard using MVC 2

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-2, wizard-control

Does anyone have any go example I could follow to create wizard in MVC 2? When using old ASP.Net you had server controls where you could other controls, and based upon how a user went through the steps you could add other steps dynamically or show other controls dynamically.

Basically, all I am trying to do is to create a wizard where based upon what answers are gain, add some other questions (controls) dynamically, and at the end of the wizard to show a table of results.

Are there any good examples out there?

Comment: Hi @Andy5, you can try this: http://afana.me/post/create-wizard-in-aspnet-mvc-3.aspx

Answer (score 0):

If you have ASP.NET MVC2 book by Steven Sanderson  great guide starts from page 477

otherwise:

nice tutorial with loads of text to read about is here (just formating is in mvc2) but from there you get the picture
http://afana.me/post/create-wizard-in-aspnet-mvc-3.aspx

Also nice part from Steven is partial vatidation, as you will need it for validation:
http://blog.stevensanderson.com/2010/02/19/partial-validation-in-aspnet-mvc-2/

here is another sample of the guide: 
http://thedotnetninja.com/index.php/2011/05/multi-step-wizard-with-asp-net-mvc-the-wizardcontroller/